# What does > nul 2>&1 mean in a batch statement

Tags: batch-file

I currently have a batch statement that looks like this

```
findstr "PreprocessorDefinitions=.*%D_KEYWORD%" %PROJ% > nul 2>&1
if errorlevel 1 (
    set D_OPT=
) else (
    set D_OPT=/D%D_KEYWORD%
)
```

I wanted to know what the following means ?

```
> nul 2>&1
```

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823643/bat-file-echo-off-but-messages-are-displayed) and it states that

```
... >nul 2>nul
```

means ignore output of command and ignore error messages

Now my question is how can I modify this command

```
 findstr "PreprocessorDefinitions=.*%D_KEYWORD%" %PROJ% > nul 2>&1
```

to show everything and not to ignore the error messages

Comment: Standard output is going to `nul` and standard error output (file descriptor 2) is being sent to standard output (file descriptor 1) so both error and normal output go to the same place. In Windows, `nul` is a null device, which means the output is just flushed and you don't see it. Thus, in this case, all output is being flushed.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up

Comment: If you want to see everything on your screen, just get rid of the `> nul 2>&1`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In the shell, what does " 2>&1 " mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-does-21-mean)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Don't use a redirection operator, which is what ">" is.

All programs have three streams:

- Standard Input (the input from the console)
- Standard Output (general logging/UI output to the console)
- Standard Error (logging/UI output to the console meant for error messages or other exceptional behavior)

> command >nul

^ This says to pipe the standard-output stream to null.

> command 2>nul

^ This says to pipe the standard-error stream to null.

> command 2>&1

^ This says to pipe the standard-error stream to the same place as the standard-output stream.

Comment: you say don't use it, but you did not explain why

Comment: ">" is actually a redirection operator; "|" is the piping operator.

Comment: @MushyPeas Agree. Very confusing.

Comment: @MushyPeas, This is a direct answer to the OP's question.  e.g. How do I see the output? Answer: Don't use the redirection operator.  Could be worded better, but it is understandable.