# How to force `findstr` to ignore `Cannot open` returns

Tags: windows, cmd, findstr

I'm trying to use `findstr` to search inside a folder looking for some string:

```
findstr /spin /c:"string" *
```

however it returns back with a lot of `Cannot open` errors which make it difficult for me to find the exact matches found.

When using `Cmder` command:

```
grep -r "string" .
```

I got `Permission denied` error for the same folders. If I use the command:

```
grep -rs "string" .
```

it gives me the results nice and clean. Is there a similar flag for `findstr` or a combination of `cmd` commands to do the same?

there are already some posts for `findstr` `Cannot open` error, explaining what is wrong and how to solve it, but I don't care why it is happening. I just want the command to ignore the `Cannot open` lines and prints out just the lines with exact matches.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make use of `2>nul`:

```
FINDSTR /SPIN /C:"string" * 2>nul
```

This will pipe the standard-error stream to null ([read more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30814001/9248774)), thus only matches are displayed.